# How to catch the exception thrown from a Spring AOP Advice

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have my own exception "MyOwnException" and throw this exception from my service class

```
public void service() throws MyOwnException
{
// some code 

}
```

Now I want to catch MyOwnException in an advice and rethrow a brand-new Exception

```
public class SimpleThrowsAdvice implements ThrowsAdvice {

    public void afterThrowing(Method method, Object[] args, Object target,
                MyOwnException ex) throws Throwable {
        throw new Exception("new Description",ex);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I catch the re-thrown `Exception` from the above Advice `SimpleThrowsAdvice`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to re-catch the already-caught-but-now-wrapped exception?  This sounds too much like it's turtles all the way down.  What do you intend to do with the new Exception catching advice that you can't do with SimpleThrowsAdvice?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Around advice to do that. See here [Spring AOP AfterThrowing vs. Around Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501955/spring-aop-afterthrowing-vs-around-advice)